# some weak conditions about Vitali convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

As we have known,the Vitali convergence theorem is stated:

Let $(X,\mathbb{M},\mu)$ be a positive measure space.If 
(i)$\mu(X)<\infty$;
(ii)$\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable;
(iii)$f_n(x)\to f(x)~~a.e.as~~n\to\infty$;
(iv)$|f(x)|<\infty~~a.e$;
then $f\in L^1(\mu)$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X |f_n-f|d\mu=0.$$

Call a set $\Phi\subset L^1(\mu)$ uniformly integrable if to each $\varepsilon>0$ corresponds a $\delta>0$ such that $$|\int_E fd\mu|<\varepsilon$$
whenever $f\in\Phi$ and $\mu(E)<\delta$.

So I want to give some weaker conditions to verify whether the Vitali theorem is still valid or not.

First,if $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $(-\infty,\infty)$,and moreover,$\{\parallel f_n\parallel_1\}$ is assumed to be bounded.How about the Vitali theorem?

Second,can we omit the hypothesis (iv) when we consider the Lebesgue measure on a bounded interval?And can this be extended to finite measures?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the strongest version of Vitali's theorem (from O. Kavian, *Introduction à la théorie des points critiques*, Springer, 1993)

**Definition.** A sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ is equi-integrable if the following condition is satisfied: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a measurable set $A$ of finite measure and there exists $\delta>0$ such that

1. for every $n \geq 1$, $\int_{\complement A} |f_n|<\varepsilon$;
2. for every measurable $E \subset \Omega$ whose measure is less than $\delta$, there results $\int_E |f_n|<\varepsilon$ for every $n \geq 1$.

**Theorem.** Let $\{f_n\}_n$ be  a sequence in $L^1(\Omega)$ that converges almost everywhere to some measurable function $f$. The sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ if and only if it is equi-integrable.

Comment: Siminore, I was wondering if you know whether an English edition of Kavians book exists? I'm guessing it doesn't because I've been looking everywhere and haven't found it yet. Also, would you happen to know of any books that are similar to it? I'm looking for books which discuss distributions of critical points for elliptic operators, whether or not the critical points are isolated or not, the types of nonlinearities that give rise to different distributions etc

Comment: No, there is no english translation. This is a really good textbook, and I must admit that it is the best I have read on the same topics. It contains a lot of important results and examples.

Comment: That's disappointing. Looks like I'll have to learn French then. Thanks for the response.